# DetailsView Update/Insert works on localhost not web server

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, detailsview

All the research I've found is talking about people who can't get this to work (insert/update in DetailsView). My code works when running through VS2012 but not when I copy the site to my web server.

DetailsView link buttons and where they work:

- Edit: Dev and Web server
- Update: **Dev only**
- Cancel: Dev and Web server
- Delete: Dev and Web server
- New: Dev and Web server
- Insert: **Dev only**

When I copy the files to my web server and run it through IE on my PC the **Update** and **Insert** link buttons do nothing when I click them as if they are not tied to anything. The **DetailsView** will go in and out of **edit mode** by clicking the **Edit** link button and then the **Cancel** link button. The **DetailsView** will go in and out of **insert mode** by clicking the **New** link button and then the **Cancel** link button.

All of the above works perfectly when running through debug mode in VS 2012 and if I just run the site using localhost which is hosted on my local IIS.

I've checked setting between my local IIS and server's IIS and they appear to be the same.

- web.config
- DefaultAppPool
- site settings like authentication, application settings, etc.

In my code below you will notice that I have 2 sets of link buttons. The ones that are set in the DetailsView tag like AutoGenerateDeleteButton="true", etc. I also have the button defined near the end of the DetalsView because I wanted more control over them like confirming deletes. I get the same results if I use either way (one set commented out) or if both are defined.

Here is my code:

```
<asp:DetailsView
    ID="dtvEmployee"
    runat="server"
    AutoGenerateRows="false"
    DataKeyNames="VHRID"
    DataSourceID="SqlEmployee"
    DefaultMode="ReadOnly"
    HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true"
    HeaderStyle-Font-Underline="true"
    HeaderText="View Item..."
    GridLines="Both" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="true" AutoGenerateEditButton="true" AutoGenerateInsertButton="true">
    <Fields>
        <%-- VHRID --%>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="VHRID" HeaderText="VHRID:" ReadOnly="true" SortExpression="VHRID" Visible="true" InsertVisible="false" />
        <%-- Firstname --%>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Firstname:" SortExpression="Firstname">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstname" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Firstname")%>' MaxLength="50" />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="txtFirstname" runat="server"
                    Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red" ID="rfvFirstname"
                    ErrorMessage="Firstname is a required field." />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <%-- Lastname --%>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Lastname:" SortExpression="Lastname">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastname" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Lastname")%>' MaxLength="50" />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="txtLastname" runat="server"
                    Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red" ID="rfvLastname"
                    ErrorMessage="Lastname is a required field." />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <%-- Username --%>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Username:" SortExpression="Username">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtUsername" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Username")%>' MaxLength="50" />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="txtUsername" runat="server"
                    Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red" ID="rfvUsername"
                    ErrorMessage="Username is a required field." />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <%-- Email --%>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email:" SortExpression="Email">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Email")%>' MaxLength="50" />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="txtEmail" runat="server"
                    Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red" ID="rfvEmail"
                    ErrorMessage="Email is a required field." />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <%-- Title --%>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Title:" SortExpression="Title">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtTitle" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("EmpTitle")%>' MaxLength="50" />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="txtTitle" runat="server"
                    Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red" ID="rfvTitle"
                    ErrorMessage="Title is a required field." />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <%-- Location --%>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Location:" SortExpression="Location">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtLocation" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Location")%>' MaxLength="50" Visible="false" />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="txtLocation" runat="server"
                    Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red" ID="rfvLocation"
                    ErrorMessage="Location is a required field." />
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlLocation" runat="server"
                    OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlLocation_SelectedIndexChanged"
                    AutoPostBack="true"
                    Width="300">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="PHX" Value="PHX" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="DEN" Value="DEN" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="LAS" Value="LAS" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="NOG" Value="NOG" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="RENO" Value="RENO" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="TUC" Value="TUC" />
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <%-- Office Number --%>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Office Number:" SortExpression="OfficeNumber">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtOfficeNumber" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("OfficeNumber")%>' MaxLength="50" Visible="false" />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="txtOfficeNumber" runat="server"
                    Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red" ID="rfvOfficeNumber"
                    ErrorMessage="Office Number is a required field." />
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlOfficeNumber" runat="server"
                    OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlOfficeNumber_SelectedIndexChanged"
                    AppendDataBoundItems="true"
                    AutoPostBack="true"
                    CausesValidation="false"
                    DataSourceID="sqlOfficeNumbers"
                    DataTextField="OfficeNumber"
                    DataValueField="Room_Num"
                    Width="300">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="None" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <%-- Office Phone --%>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Office Phone:" SortExpression="OfficePhone">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtOfficePhone" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("OfficePhone")%>' MaxLength="50"  />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="txtOfficePhone" runat="server"
                    Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red" ID="rfvOfficePhone"
                    ErrorMessage="Office Phone is a required field." />
                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ControlToValidate="txtOfficePhone" runat="server"
                    Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red" ID="revOfficePhone"
                    ValidationExpression="^[2-9]\d{2}\d{3}\d{4}$" EnableClientScript="false"
                    ErrorMessage="Office Phone must be 9 numeric digits." />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <%-- Show Photo --%>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Show Photo:" SortExpression="ShowPhoto">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkShowPhoto" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("ShowPhoto")%>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <%-- Status --%>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status:" SortExpression="Status">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtStatus" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Status")%>' MaxLength="50" Visible="false" />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="txtStatus" runat="server"
                    Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red" ID="rfvStatus"
                    ErrorMessage="Status is a required field." />
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStatus" runat="server"
                    OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlStatus_SelectedIndexChanged"
                    AutoPostBack="true"
                    Width="300">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Active" Value="Active" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Terminated" Value="Terminated" />
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <%-- LinkButtons and the modes they show up in --%>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%-- DetailsView - ReadOnly Mode --%>
                <asp:linkbutton ID="lnkEdit" Text="Edit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" CausesValidation="false"></asp:linkbutton>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDelete" Text="Delete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" CausesValidation="false" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?');"></asp:LinkButton>
                <asp:linkbutton ID="lnkNew" Text="New" runat="server" CommandName="New" CausesValidation="false"></asp:linkbutton>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <%-- DetailsView - Edit Mode --%>
                <asp:linkbutton ID="lnkUpdate" Text="Update" runat="server" CommandName="Update"></asp:linkbutton>
                <asp:linkbutton ID="lnkCancel" Text="Cancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" CausesValidation="false"></asp:linkbutton>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <%-- DetailsView - Insert Mode --%>
                <asp:linkbutton ID="lnkInsert" Text="Insert" runat="server" CommandName="Insert"></asp:linkbutton>
                <asp:linkbutton ID="lnkCancel" Text="Cancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" CausesValidation="false"></asp:linkbutton>
            </InsertItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
```

Here is the SQLDatasource:

```
<%-- For DetailsView --%>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlEmployee" runat="server"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DWStageConnectionString %>"
    DeleteCommand="UPDATE [MasterTempEmployeeStage] SET
        [IsDeleted] = 1
        WHERE [VHRID] = @VHRID"
    InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [MasterTempEmployeeStage] (
        [Firstname], [Lastname]
        , [Location], [Username]
        , [Email], [EmpTitle]
        , [OfficeNumber], [OfficePhone]
        , [ShowPhoto], [Status]
        ) VALUES (
        @Firstname, @Lastname
        , @Location, @Username
        , @Email, @EmpTitle
        , @OfficeNumber, @OfficePhone
        , @ShowPhoto, @Status);
        SELECT @VHRID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();"
    SelectCommand="SELECT [VHRID]
        , [Firstname], [Lastname]
        , [Location], [Username]
        , [Email], [EmpTitle]
        , [OfficeNumber], [OfficePhone]
        , [ShowPhoto], [Status]
        FROM [MasterTempEmployeeStage]
        WHERE [VHRID] = @VHRID
        ORDER BY [Lastname], [Firstname]"
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE [MasterTempEmployeeStage] SET
        [Firstname] = @Firstname
        , [Lastname] = @Lastname
        , [Location] = @Location
        , [Username] = @Username
        , [Email] = @Email
        , [EmpTitle] = @EmpTitle
        , [OfficeNumber] = @OfficeNumber
        , [OfficePhone] = @OfficePhone
        , [ShowPhoto] = @ShowPhoto
        , [Status] = @Status
        WHERE [VHRID] = @VHRID">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlEmployees" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Name="VHRID" />
    </SelectParameters>
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlEmployees" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Name="VHRID" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="VHRID" Direction="Output" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Firstname" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Lastname" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Location" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Username" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Email" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="EmpTitle" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="OfficeNumber" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="OfficePhone" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="ShowPhoto" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Status" Type="String" />
    </InsertParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Firstname" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Lastname" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Location" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Username" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Email" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="EmpTitle" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="OfficeNumber" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="OfficePhone" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="ShowPhoto" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Status" Type="String" />
        <%--<asp:Parameter Name="VHRID" Type="Int32" />--%>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlEmployees" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Name="VHRID" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the resolution and I have no idea why it would work on my Dev PC and not the actual web server to begin with but here it is.

I had to set CausesValidation="false" on the Insert and Update link buttons. Setting this is something you cannot do if you use the AutoGenerateEditButton="true"*and others in the DetailsView definition.

As a test I:

- Removed the link buttons that I defined near the bottom of the DetailsView
- Left the auto ones in the DetailsView tag
- Removed all validators

Copied the above to the web server and it all works. So not setting the CausesValidation to false on the Update and Insert link buttons prevented them from firing. Since I want the validators I did this...

- Removed the auto generate link buttons from the DetailsView
- Used the link buttons near the bottom of the DetailsView
- Set CausesValidation to false on the update and insert link buttons
- Put my validators back

All is now working properly.

See below for the new code that works:

```
<asp:DetailsView
    ID="dtvEmployee"
    runat="server"
    AutoGenerateRows="false"
    DataKeyNames="VHRID"
    DataSourceID="SqlEmployee"
    DefaultMode="ReadOnly"
    HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true"
    HeaderStyle-Font-Underline="true"
    HeaderText="View Item..."
    GridLines="Both">
    <Fields>
        <%-- VHRID --%>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="VHRID" HeaderText="VHRID:" ReadOnly="true" SortExpression="VHRID" Visible="true" InsertVisible="false" />
        <%-- Firstname --%>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Firstname:" SortExpression="Firstname">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstname" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Firstname")%>' MaxLength="50" />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="txtFirstname" runat="server"
                    Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red" ID="rfvFirstname"
                    ErrorMessage="Firstname is a required field." />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <%-- Lastname --%>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Lastname:" SortExpression="Lastname">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastname" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Lastname")%>' MaxLength="50" />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="txtLastname" runat="server"
                    Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red" ID="rfvLastname"
                    ErrorMessage="Lastname is a required field." />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <%-- Username --%>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Username:" SortExpression="Username">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtUsername" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Username")%>' MaxLength="50" />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="txtUsername" runat="server"
                    Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red" ID="rfvUsername"
                    ErrorMessage="Username is a required field." />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <%-- Email --%>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email:" SortExpression="Email">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Email")%>' MaxLength="50" />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="txtEmail" runat="server"
                    Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red" ID="rfvEmail"
                    ErrorMessage="Email is a required field." />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <%-- Title --%>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Title:" SortExpression="Title">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtTitle" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("EmpTitle")%>' MaxLength="50" />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="txtTitle" runat="server"
                    Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red" ID="rfvTitle"
                    ErrorMessage="Title is a required field." />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <%-- Location --%>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Location:" SortExpression="Location">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtLocation" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Location")%>' MaxLength="50" Visible="false" />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="txtLocation" runat="server"
                    Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red" ID="rfvLocation"
                    ErrorMessage="Location is a required field." />
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlLocation" runat="server"
                    OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlLocation_SelectedIndexChanged"
                    AutoPostBack="true"
                    Width="300">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="PHX" Value="PHX" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="DEN" Value="DEN" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="LAS" Value="LAS" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="NOG" Value="NOG" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="RENO" Value="RENO" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="TUC" Value="TUC" />
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <%-- Office Number --%>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Office Number:" SortExpression="OfficeNumber">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtOfficeNumber" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("OfficeNumber")%>' MaxLength="50" Visible="false" />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="txtOfficeNumber" runat="server"
                    Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red" ID="rfvOfficeNumber"
                    ErrorMessage="Office Number is a required field." />
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlOfficeNumber" runat="server"
                    OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlOfficeNumber_SelectedIndexChanged"
                    AppendDataBoundItems="true"
                    AutoPostBack="true"
                    CausesValidation="false"
                    DataSourceID="sqlOfficeNumbers"
                    DataTextField="OfficeNumber"
                    DataValueField="Room_Num"
                    Width="300">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="None" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <%-- Office Phone --%>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Office Phone:" SortExpression="OfficePhone">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtOfficePhone" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("OfficePhone")%>' MaxLength="50"  />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="txtOfficePhone" runat="server"
                    Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red" ID="rfvOfficePhone"
                    ErrorMessage="Office Phone is a required field." />
                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ControlToValidate="txtOfficePhone" runat="server"
                    Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red" ID="revOfficePhone"
                    ValidationExpression="^[2-9]\d{2}\d{3}\d{4}$" EnableClientScript="false"
                    ErrorMessage="Office Phone must be 9 numeric digits." />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <%-- Show Photo --%>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Show Photo:" SortExpression="ShowPhoto">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkShowPhoto" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("ShowPhoto")%>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <%-- Status --%>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status:" SortExpression="Status">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtStatus" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Status")%>' MaxLength="50" Visible="false" />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="txtStatus" runat="server"
                    Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red" ID="rfvStatus"
                    ErrorMessage="Status is a required field." />
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStatus" runat="server"
                    OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlStatus_SelectedIndexChanged"
                    AutoPostBack="true"
                    Width="300">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Active" Value="Active" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Terminated" Value="Terminated" />
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <%-- LinkButtons and the modes they show up in --%>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%-- DetailsView - ReadOnly Mode --%>
                <asp:linkbutton ID="lnkEdit" Text="Edit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" CausesValidation="false"></asp:linkbutton>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDelete" Text="Delete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" CausesValidation="false" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?');"></asp:LinkButton>
                <asp:linkbutton ID="lnkNew" Text="New" runat="server" CommandName="New" CausesValidation="false"></asp:linkbutton>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <%-- DetailsView - Edit Mode --%>
                <asp:linkbutton ID="lnkUpdate" Text="Update" runat="server" CommandName="Update" CausesValidation="false"></asp:linkbutton>
                <asp:linkbutton ID="lnkCancel" Text="Cancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" CausesValidation="false"></asp:linkbutton>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <%-- DetailsView - Insert Mode --%>
                <asp:linkbutton ID="lnkInsert" Text="Insert" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" CausesValidation="false"></asp:linkbutton>
                <asp:linkbutton ID="lnkCancel" Text="Cancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" CausesValidation="false"></asp:linkbutton>
            </InsertItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
```

Comment: This also helped. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19288749/detailsview-itemcommand-event-not-firing